# Converting data table to matrix R

Tags: r, reshape

I have a data table with sample locations, species names and densities that looks like this:

```
    location     species    density
2   Abludomelita obtusata   12,92
3   Abludomelita obtusata   142,119
17  Abludomelita obtusata   12,92
42  Abludomelita obtusata   12,92
93  Abludomelita obtusata   12,92
2   Abra alba   155,039
3   Abra alba   710,594
6   Abra alba   12,92
15  Abra alba   12,92
17  Abra alba   12,92
18  Abra alba   38,76
27  Abra alba   684,755
```

and I want to convert it into a matrix-type table like this

```
Location    Abludomelita obtusata   Abra alba   etc
1   na  na  
2   12,92   155,039 
3   142,119 710,594
```

I tried `xtabs (xtabs(density ~ location + species,*filename*, na.action=0)`, but for some reason that did not work
Thanks for your ideas
Arjen

Comment: Try both with `df <- as.matrix(df)` or `df <- matrix(df,nrow=nr, ncol=nc)` specifying these parameters. Nevertheless, remember that a matrix should be compsed only by numeric values.

Comment: Google "R reshape wide format". Also, why have you tagged this with [tag:sparse-matrix]?

Comment: @Roland: I tried the `reshape` command, and that worked. Thanks. The sparse-matrix tag needs to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
library(reshape)
df <- data.frame(
location = c(2,3, 17, 42, 93, 2, 3, 6),
species = c('Abludomelita', 'Abludomelita', 'Abludomelita', 'Abludomelita', 'Abludomelita', 'Abra Alba', 'Abra Alba', 'Abra Alba'), 
density = c(12.92, 112.12, 123.12, 13.14, 16.23, 17.19, 76.12, 13.32))


cast(df, location ~ species)
```